# drupal multisite and symbolic links with various subdomains

Tags: 7, multi-sites, subsites

i create two subdomains **dev.example.com** and **dev1.example.com** in cpnael admin and i create a drupal installation in public_html/dev/sites/ and i create two folders dev and dev1 inside of sites and your own database and the sites.php your settings are

```
<?php
$sites['dev.example.com'] = 'dev';
$sites['dev1.example.com'] = 'dev1';
?>
```

i create symbolink links in this way

> ls -s ~/public_html/dev ~/public_html/dev1

working good **dev.example.com** but no **dev1.example.com**

but in this way **dev1.example.com/dev** and working the other installation, how to make this work enter to **dev1.example.com** instead **dev1.example.com/dev**?

thanks

Comment: my solution is ls -s ~/public_html/dev/* ~/public_html/dev1

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what the symbolic links are for. Normally, you would add another web server virtual host for dev1.example.com pointing to the same Drupal root directory as dev.example.com.